# Is it possible to make a matrix including nonlinear equalities in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have this constraint in my code.

```
 i=number of supplier
 p=type of productions
 t=number of period
 constraint=con1[i=1:3,p=1:2,t=1:3],E(I)[i,p,t ]=
 sum(Q[i,p,s] fors=1:t)-sum(E(D)[i,p,t]+E(W)[i,p,s] for s=1:t )) 

 E(I)=((sigmaI/miuI)+sigmaI)*exp(((I[i,p,t]-miuI)/sigmaI)^2)
 E(w)[i,p,t]=((sigmaw/miuw)+sigmaw)*exp(((w[i,p,t]-miuw)/sigmaw)^2)
```

they are expected value of inventory and waste of products. as well as w and I are decision variables. 
I would like to save all the expected value equations in one matrix[3,2,3].
Is it possible in Julia?
Pleas help me.
thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You set this up as a rootfinding problem to solve for `x` in some array equation `G(x)=0` and use a package like [NLsolve.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/NLsolve.jl).